Is it possible to update json data in vanilla javascript?
Like title says. I dont know how to update json data in vanilla javascript.. If you know how to do it please tell me if its even possible. If its not please help me with this. I can provide you info if you want to help me :)
I am trying to update my players.json data that looks like this with vanilla javascript without any framework or api:
"players": [
{
"name": "S1mple",
"all_time_stats": {
"kills": 0,
"headshots": 0,
"headshot_percentage": 0,
"deaths": 0,
"kill_death_ratio": 0
}
},
(there is more but that is one example)
I have tried to do alot of things but nothing worked. I know how to fetch info from json but i dont know how to store/update the data to the json.
Some people says that node.js can handle this but i dont want to add some extra to the javascript because this is localhost project and is for learning puproses for me.
This is what i tried but did not work:
saveToJson() {
  let jsonFilePath = "../data/players.json";

  fetch(jsonFilePath)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.players.length; i++) {
        if (data.players[i].name === this.name) {
          data.players[i].all_time_stats.kills = this.kills;
          data.players[i].all_time_stats.headshots = this.headshots;
          data.players[i].all_time_stats.deaths = this.deaths;
          break;
        }
      }

      fetch(jsonFilePath, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
    });
}


By "update", do you mean: read a JSON file from the server and parse it, then modify it, then rewrite it to the server?

What errors are you getting? You can definitely take a JSON object parse it, modify it and the stringify it.

Whether PUT works depends on the configuration of the server. Other than that, I don't see a problem with your code.

it's unlikely that a server will allow PUT without authentication, since that would allow anyone to modify these files.

@Sean yeah, thats what i am trying to do.

@BGPHiJACK the error i am getting is this:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

This isn't possible. Vanilla front-end javascript cannot write anything to the server. It can send a message to the server, but the server needs to have server-side code waiting to receive it and then that server-side code can write a file to the server.

@Sean ok. I have always used js without any server-side code so i dont know anything about it. so could you tell me how i can make some server side code?

@Niklas20 You can start by researching NodeJS or PHP. Someone below has provided NodeJS code as an answer.

You are using frontend JavaScript, meaning that all your code is run on the client (the user). The client can't modify the server's files.
To do this, you can setup a server and send the JSON from the client to the server, using fetch(). In the code below, I have created an express server that serves your static files, and an endpoint that can modify the file.
const express = require("express"); // npm i express
const fs = require("fs"); // the filesystem module can modify files
const path = require("path"); // fs needs absolute paths


const server = express(); // create an express app

server.use(express.static("public")); // this will serve all the files in ./public

server.post("/modify", async (req, res) => {
    // Get the JSON data from the request body
    const json = req.body;

    // Save the JSON data to a file
    fs.writeFile(
        path.join(__dirname, "public", "myFile.json"),
        JSON.stringify(json), "utf-8", (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Error writing file:", err);
                res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
            } else {
                console.log("File saved successfully");
                res.send("File saved successfully");
            }
    });
});

server.listen(80); // start the webserver on port 80

You can fetch the JSON in the same way, but on your client, use this code to modify the file:
fetch("/modify", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: jsonData
});

Just remember that the client cannot modify the server on it's own, and this will not be possible on a static site.

This project is localhost without any framework or apis. the fs is node.js if i am not wrong. So this is not able to be made with vanilla js without nay framework or api?

@Niklas20 you can create your own server without any modules, but it may take more time and more code.

how? i have never done anythin server side so i dont know anything about it. can you tell what i have to do and how? Thank you!

@Niklas20 You should start by doing some research on your own, then attempt to implement it. If you get stuck, make a new question post on Stack Overflow showing what you've tried and where you're stuck. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

@Sean i have researched alot about this but like everyone says it could be possible with nodejs so i will use it i guess.. but the thing is can i add nodejs to my project after i have made my project? this is question that i have not got any answer no matter how much research i have made.

JSON is an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation, which makes it particularly easy to manipulate in JavaScript, as it is (almost) executable JavaScript as it comes.
So, the answer to your question "Is it possible to update json data in vanilla javascript?" is definitely, yes.
Just call var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString).
Then you can directly manipulate the JavaScript object: obj.someValue = newValue
You can convert it back to a string if you need to send/save it somewhere using JSON.stringify(obj)
When it comes to your code though, it looks like you're trying to update a json file located on a server. Do you operate the server, and have access to the server code, or are you accessing a public API?
Your code does request that the server update the players.json to the values you specified, but if this is a public API it is very likely that the request is unauthorised and it will be impossible to update the data directly, as you are requesting. This is by design to prevent cheating in the game. Usually as a client, you are untrusted and cannot write any data to a leaderboard/stats API.

this project is localhost so i do not operate on some online server. all these are in vanilla js and without any API.

JavaScript running in a web browser usually doesn't have access to local files for security reasons. Most of the time you don't need file access though. If you want to save to the device, use the Web Storage API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

@Kynohei Kaneko so there is no way to save it to the local files?

@Niklas20 not without requiring user input. The user would have to be offered a download and then choose to save the file somewhere. Why do you want to save to a file? If it's for saving game state then use the Web Storage API as I stated above. You can even just save your json in a single entry.

@Kynohei Kaneko i am making a counter strike game with the players having all time stats. so i can check who performs best.

@Niklas20 if you need to record player's stats you'll need a server, otherwise how will you compare the stats? In your current setup the stats are on each player's device but they don't have access to anyone else's.

Kaneo thats what i am trying to do. every player should play ther own game and their players have  different stats than other players. this game is localhost game and wont be uploaded to online. this is just for me . i am trying to learn js more.

@Niklas20 then you can just use the Web Storage API, following the link I showed you above. Try to look up online how to use it if you get stuck, and if you get really stuck and there's no applicable information about your problem, then create a new question here describing the specific problem you are having, as clearly as possible, and describing exactly what you've tried yourself

Do the Web storage stay for permanently? i want them to be permament saves and whenever i go back and play the game all the stats would be there still?

@Niklas20 All the info about Web Storage is available from the article I linked. Have a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API. Keep in mind that players can delete their saves by clearing their browser data though. So, it is only as permanent as the player wants it to be.

thats what i want actually. Thanks for helping me! :)
